# How to center-align a Textfield in a VStack?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to port an Android application to iOS. I would like for the textfield to be aligned in the middle. How do I achieve this? Here is the code so far:

```
var body: some View
{
    GeometryReader
    {
        metrics in
        
        VStack (alignment: .center)
        {
            Text("Lazuli Social")
        .font(.largeTitle)
    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.02, green: 0.325, blue: 1.0))
    
            TextField("Username or email", text: $user)
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        .frame(width:  metrics.size.width*0.80)
        .background(Color.orange)

        }
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `alignment` of the `frame` of the `VStack`. You'll also want to set the `maxWidth` to `infinity` so it expands.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var user = ""
    
    var body: some View
    {
        GeometryReader
        {
            metrics in
            VStack
            {
                Text("Lazuli Social")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.02, green: 0.325, blue: 1.0))
                
                TextField("Username or email", text: $user)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .frame(width:  metrics.size.width*0.80)
                    .background(Color.orange)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center) //<-- Here
        }
    }
}
```

In general, you may want to try to avoid using `GeometryReader` except when you absolutely need a size. For example, here, you may want to try `padding` instead (albeit it gives a slightly different result -- it'll no longer be 80% of the width all the time).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var user = ""
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Text("Lazuli Social")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.02, green: 0.325, blue: 1.0))
            TextField("Username or email", text: $user)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .background(Color.orange)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try:
.multilineTextAlignment(.center)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).